# calling and iterating over function return value using ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, http

I am currently refactoring my main controller in my small AngularJS application after reading about [mocking server dependancies in JS and AngularJS apps](http://cliffmeyers.com/blog/2013/8/27/mocking-server-dependencies-in-javascript-and-angularjs-applications).

In my markup I iterate over the "main events" using the `ng-repeat` directive:

This is my AngularJS module, refactored repository and controller.

However I am unable to access the main event array in this way - what am I missing?

```
// Module
var app = angular.module('MainEventApp', ['cloudinary']);

// Repository
app.service('MainEventRepository', ['$http', function($http) {

    this.$http = $http;

    this.getMainEvents = function() {

        return [
        {
            id: 1,
            roman_numeral: 'I',
            name: 'Hulk Hogan & Mr T vs Rowdy Roddy Piper & Paul Orndorff',
            venue: 'Madison Square Garden',
            state: 'New York',
            attendance: 19121
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            roman_numeral: 'II',
            name: 'Hulk Hogan vs King Kong Bundy',
            venue: 'Split-Transmission',
            state: 'New York/Illinois/California',
            attendance: 40085
        }
        ];
  };

}]);

// Controller
app.controller("MainEventCtrl", ['$scope', 'MainEventRepository', function ($scope, MainEventRepository) {

    MainEventRepository.getMainEvents().then(function(main_events) {
        //$scope.main_events = main_events;
        return main_events;
    });    

}]);
```

My live application can be seen [here](http://www.wrestlemaniamainevent.com/) (not yet refactored).

Comment: Please include your markup. If you apply methods to 'this', you need to use the controllerAs syntax in the router or ng-controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to use main_events in your markup you need to have this property in your controller scope.

Second, your service returns simple array, but in your controller you use it as if it would return promise.

So, your controller code should be something linke this:

```
app.controller("MainEventCtrl", ['$scope', 'MainEventRepository', function ($scope, MainEventRepository) {

    $scope.main_events = MainEventRepository.getMainEvents();

}]);
```

And your markup:

```
<li ng-repeat="event in main_events"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add main_events to your scope.

```
MainEventRepository.getMainEvents().then(function(main_events) {
    //$scope.main_events = main_events;
    return main_events;
});
```

Why is the first line in that promise commented out?